# How to generate cited references with biber and xelatex

Tags: org-mode, latex, bibtex

I would like to generate cited references and bibliography using biber and xelatex through org mode, but have not figured out how to do so.

I have to use xelatex because I am working with Chinese articles.

## Sample Document:

```org
#+TITLE: How to Automate Footnote Citations in Org-Mode
#+AUTHOR: Sati Bodhi

* Cite Test

This is a statement with a footnote reference. [fn:2a55720f42c74dd:This is the footnote with a citation that is supposed to be formatted in Chicago-fullnote style. cite:Rogersbecoming1995。]


bibliography:thesis.bib
bibliographystyle:chicago-notes
```

## Bibtex Entry:

```bibtex
@book{Rogersbecoming1995,
  title = {On Becoming a Person: A Therapist's View of Psychotherapy},
  author = {Rogers, Carl R.},
  year = {1995},
  publisher = {{Houghton Mifflin}},
  address = {{Boston, New York}},
  abstract = {Collection of essays by American psychotherapist Carl Rogers written between 1951 and 1961, in which he put forth his ideas about self-esteem, flexibility, respect for self, and acceptance of others.},
  isbn = {9780395755310},
  keywords = {Client-centered psychotherapy},
  language = {eng},
  place = {;}
}
```

## Configuration:

```elisp
(setq org-latex-classes
      '(("article"
         "
%\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{ctexart}

\\usepackage{xeCJK}
\\usepackage{zhnumber} % package for Chinese formatting of date time (use /zhtoday)
%\\usepackage[yyyymmdd]{datetime} % set date time to numeric

% For Generation of Citations and Bibliography
\\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

% Set Font.
\\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\\setmainfont{Calibri} % Set serifed font to Calibri. Originally set to 'Times New Roman', but it cannot display certain characters such as ①②③.
\\setCJKmainfont{Songti TC}
\\setCJKsansfont{Kaiti TC} % Set Chinese font. NOTE: Remember to append CJK before of the font class. CJK HAS to be there for the font to show.
\\setCJKmonofont{PingFang TC}

% Set title font.
\\renewcommand{\\maketitlehooka}{\\sffamily}

% Set quotation font.
\\usepackage{etoolbox}
\\newCJKfontfamily\\quotefont{Kaiti TC}
\\AtBeginEnvironment{quote}{\\quotefont\\normalsize}

% Tweak default settings.
\\renewcommand{\\baselinestretch}{1.2} % Set line width.
%\\renewcommand{\\contentsname}{\\hfill\\bfseries\\Large 目\\hspace{0.5cm} 次\\hfill} % Translate content page title to Chinese.
%\\renewcommand{\\cftaftertoctitle}{\\hfill} % Center contents title.

% For text-boxes

\\usepackage{mdframed}
\\BeforeBeginEnvironment{minted}{\\begin{mdframed}}
\\AfterEndEnvironment{minted}{\\end{mdframed}}

% For tables

\\usepackage{float}
\\restylefloat{table}

% [FIXME] ox-latex 的設計不良導致 hypersetup 必須在這裡插入
\\usepackage{hyperref}
\\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, %把紅框框移掉改用字體顏色不同來顯示連結
  linkcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  citecolor=[rgb]{0,0.47,0.68},
  filecolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  urlcolor=[rgb]{0,0.37,0.53},
  pagebackref=true,
  linktoc=all,}
"
         ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
         ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
         ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
         ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
         ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}"))
        ))

(setq org-latex-with-hyperref t)

(setq org-latex-default-packages-alist
      '(("" "hyperref" nil)
        ("" "graphicx" t)
        ("" "longtable" nil)
        ("" "wrapfig" nil)
        ("" "rotating" nil)
        ("normalem" "ulem" t)
        ("" "amsmath" t)
        ("" "textcomp" t)))

;; Use XeLaTeX to export PDF in Org-mode
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))

(require 'ox-latex)
(setq org-latex-inputenc-alist '(("utf8" . "utf8x")))

;; Use XeLaTeX to compile in Latex-mode

(setq tex-compile-commands '(("xelatex %r")))
(setq tex-command "xelatex")
(setq-default TeX-engine 'xetex)
```

## Generated Bibliography and Footnote:

[image: Bibliography]

[image: Footnote]

---

## Update:

I've found my own solution. Because I cannot award myself the bounty, I would like to seek an explanation as to *why* the bibliography and style had to be hard-coded this way and whether, given the current working solution, there can be a more flexible way of dealing with this. The best answer would be awarded the bounty.

## Note:

The format used to specify the bibliography data source and its citation style in the question above was one offered by [org-ref](https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my own solution.
Here are the changes I've made to the source and configuration code that made this work.

## Source:

```org
#+TITLE: How to Automate Footnote Citations in Org-Mode
#+AUTHOR: Sati Bodhi

#+BEGIN_abstract
This is the abstract.
#+END_abstract

* Cite Test

This is a statement with a footnote reference. [fn:2a55720f42c74dd:This is the footnote with a citation that is supposed to be formatted in Chicago-fullnote style. [[cite:Rogersbecoming1995][121-127]]。]


#+LATEX: \printbibliography
```

## Configuration:

```latex
% For Generation of Citations and Bibliography
\\usepackage[notes, isbn=false, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\\bibliography{/Users/satibodhi/Creation/notes/bibliography/thesis}
```

```elisp
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
      '("xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "biber --output-directory %o $(basename %f .tex)"
        "xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
        "xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
```

## Results:

[image]
[image]